# Pivot spark scala dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-1.6

I am trying to use pivot method in scala-spark

```
val dfOutput =  df_input.groupBy("memberlogin").pivot("country_group2").count()
```

However, though there isn't any compliation error while creating a jar in eclipse, 
while execution in spark, its giving error as  --
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:`

```
org.apache.spark.sql.GroupedData.pivot(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/GroupedData;
```

I have imported the desired libraries,

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.GroupedData
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions
```

also,

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
```

as few other threads claimed.

Its not working, and unable to understand, can someone help or guide in direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pivoting feature introduced in `Spark 1.6` please check this documentation [Reshaping Data with Pivot in Apache Spark](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/09/reshaping-data-with-pivot-in-apache-spark.html) . Check the `API` [Pivot Api](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.GroupedData)

Answer (score 0):

Pivoting feature was added in `Spark 1.6` and it make possible creating pivot tables, with a `DataFrame` (with Scala, Java, or Python).